# Issue with z-order of elements in SVG being rendered incorrectly

Tags: svg

I created an SVG image as defined by the code below. The issue I am having is that the SVG image is being rendered incorrectly. The z-order of the elements in my SVG are incorrectly being rendered.

**Issue:** There are 3x rectangles (color = white), which are above another rectangle (color=red). These 3x rectangles are positioned to have the same y-axis as the red rectangle behind it and have the same height. Despite this positioning/height, there is a "red" border that seems to be visible on the edge of the white rectangle due to the red rectangle in the back. It seems that z-order or stacking order of the elements in the rendered image is not being respected.

Below is a screenshot of the SVG image open in the Inkscape showing the issue. Even after converting the SVG image to [PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixVB6.png), the z-order issue still existing.

After troubleshooting with the position, I noticed the issue randomly disappears depending on the value of the y-axis position, or SVG image size (pixels/width/height). For example, if you change edit the SVG from `y="2.5807"` to `y="2.5"`, the issue goes however. However, this is a NOT a feasible solution for my issue, but the exact positing and SVG image size properties is are fixed can shouldn't be changed.

**Updates**

- I tried @Robert Longson suggestion of using `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` on the root SVG. It did NOT solve the issue for my use case. Using his suggestion, it does solve the issue on how the image is rendered in a browser, however the issue is still visible in Inkscape or when SVG is converted to PNG. For my use case, I care about how the SVG is rendered after being converted to PNG.
- I just found out `shape-rendering="crispEdges` does work when SVG is converted to PNG, but its dependent on how the conversion process works. If I use `rsvg-convert` command in Bash, which is provided by *librsvg2-bin*, to convert the SVG to PNG, the issue is fixed. However, if I use `convert` command in Bash, which is provided by *ImageMagick*, the issue still exist. If open the SVG file in Inkscape and then Export as PNG, then the issue still exist.

[image]

```
<svg baseProfile="full" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="912px" height="1140px" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0,0,8.0,5.0">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="8.0" height="5.0" fill="white" />
    <rect x="0" y="2.5807" width="8.0" height="1.0" fill="red" />
    <g transform="translate(2.9275,0)">
        <rect x="0" y="2.5807" width="0.5" height="1.0" fill="white" />
        <rect x="1.0" y="2.5807" width="1.0" height="1.0" fill="white" />
        <rect x="2.5" y="2.5807" width="1.5" height="1.0" fill="white" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

that's antialiasing you can turn it off with shape-rendering="crispEdges"

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="912px" height="1140px" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0,0,8.0,5.0" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="8.0" height="5.0" fill="white" />
    <rect x="0" y="2.5807" width="8.0" height="1.0" fill="red" />
    <g transform="translate(2.9275,0)">
        <rect x="0" y="2.5807" width="0.5" height="1.0" fill="white" />
        <rect x="1.0" y="2.5807" width="1.0" height="1.0" fill="white" />
        <rect x="2.5" y="2.5807" width="1.5" height="1.0" fill="white" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions of using the 'shape-rendering'. It does solve how the SVG image is rendered in a browser but it does NOT solve the issue when the SVG image is rendered in Inkscape or when the SVG is converted to a PNG file. For my end use case, I care about how the image looks when the SVG is converted to PNG.

Comment: I just found out `shape-rendering="crispEdges` does work when SVG is converted to PNG, but its dependent on how the conversion process works. If I use `rsvg-convert` command in Bash, which is provided by *librsvg2-bin*, to convert the SVG to PNG, the issue is fixed. However, if I use `convert` command in Bash, which is provided by *ImageMagick*, the issue still exist. If open the SVG file in Inkscape and then Export as PNG, then the issue still exist.